# Asymptotic of binomial coeficient

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I was doing a problem, and I found that I needed to calculate asymptotics for
$$ \frac{1}{{n - k \choose k}}$$
Supposing $n = k^2$.

Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try pluging the Stirling approximation?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{%
{k^{2} - k \choose k}^{-1}
=
{k!\left(k^{2} - 2k\right)! \over \left(k^{2} - k\right)!}.\quad
\mbox{Use Stirling's formula:}\
N! \sim \sqrt{2\pi\,}\,N^{N\ +\ 1/2}\,{\rm e}^{-N}\,,\quad N \gg 1.}$

\begin{align}
\left.{k^{2} - k \choose k}^{-1}\right\vert_{k\ \gg\ 1}
&\sim
{\left[\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}\,k^{k\ +\ 1/2}\,{\rm e}^{-k}\right]
 \left[\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}\,
 \left(k^{2} - 2k\right)^{k^{2} - 2k\ +\ 1/2}\,{\rm e}^{-k^{2}\ +\ 2k}\right]
 \over
 \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}\,\left(k^{2}\ - k\right)^{k^{2}\ -\ k\ +\ 1/2}\,
 {\rm e}^{-k^{2}\ +\ k}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}}\,
{k^{k + 1/2}
 \left[k^{2k^{2}\ -\ 4k\ +\ 1}\left(1 - 2/k\right)^{k^{2}\ -\ 2k\ +\ 1/2}\right]
 \over
 k^{2k^{2}\ -\ 2k\ +\ 1}\left(1 - 1/k\right)^{k^{2}\ -\ k\ +\ 1/2}}
\\[3mm]&\sim
{1 \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}}\,k^{-k + 1/2}
{\rm e}^{-k + 3/2}
\end{align}

since $\left(~\mbox{for}\ k \gg 1~\right)$:
\begin{align}
\left(k^{2} - 2k + {1 \over 2}\right)\ln\left(1 - {2 \over k}\right)
&\sim
-2k + 2 + {1 \over 3k} + {1 \over 3k^{2}} + \cdots
\\[3mm]
\left(k^{2} - k + {1 \over 2}\right)\ln\left(1 - {1 \over k}\right)
&\sim
-k + {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 3\,k} - {1 \over 6\,k^{2}}
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
{k^{2} - k \choose k}^{-1}
\sim
{{\rm e}^{3/2} \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\pi\,}}\,
{{\rm e}^{-k} \over k^{k - 1/2}}\,,\quad k \gg 1\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Stirling yields
$$
{k^2\choose k}^{-1}\sim\sqrt{2\pi\mathrm e^3k}\cdot(k\mathrm e)^{-k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is approximation of ${n\choose k}$ using Entropy function as follows:

$$
{n\choose np}\approx e^{nH(p)}
$$
where $H(p)=-p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)$. To use this, we can choose $p=\frac{1}{k-1}$ and we get:
$$
{k^2-k\choose k}\approx e^{k^2H(\frac{1}{k-1})}
$$